# How to keep the token price in uniswap the same with the centralized exchange

Tags: uniswap

Consider I have a custom `Erc20` Token which already lists in CEX(centralized exchange like huobi). Then I `add liquidity` to [Uniswap](https://app.uniswap.org/) to make it tradable with initial exchange price. However this token is not popular and even no one trades it in Uniswap, while the price in CEX changes daily, then how can I keep the price same with CEX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a traditional order book based market-making yourself to keep it the price in sync with any centralised exchange.

- Make buys/sells on Uniswap
- Move tokens to a CEX
- Sell/buy tokens on a CEX to move the price

... or do it in a reverse order.