# Token Price on Swap and CEX/DEX

Tags: tokens, erc-20, uniswap, exchanges, pancakeswap

My question is actually almost similar with this one :
[How to keep the token price in uniswap the same with the centralized exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87316/how-to-keep-the-token-price-in-uniswap-the-same-with-the-centralized-exchange)

I want to know how to sync token price more deeply :

1. From the link above the solution is to make an order book, where the creator then will try to keep sync the price between the Exchange and the Swap, by doing buy/sell to it's own token. Is this really the only way ?
2. What about the price sync between pool in swap ? Let say, I made Alpha Token and make two pair of pools on uniswap, such as: ETH/ALP pair and DAI/ALP pair. DAI/ALP pool has more activities than ETH/ALP, so the Alpha price is out of sync between pools from initial value. Is the solution going to be the same ? (manually manipulating token price by buy and sell) Is that really how others doing it ?
3. I tested on Uniswap testnet, I made USDT/ALP pair pool only, so other can change it using USDT. But if they try to swap ALP token using UNI token, it is not available, because no pool with UNI/ALP existed. Then I try to use pancake swap, for RACA Token for quick check, somehow it is able to be swapped with any token. Is that means RACA has pools for every token or pancakeswap and uniswap provide pools pair with different behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe this is the only way
2. You would have to do it manually or use the SDK to create a backend script as an order book for maintaining the prices, if you're the owner of the token, you would have those tokens to add liquidity in the pool and manipulate the price
3. Yes, you would need to create a pool for every swap you do with a new token & yes, raca probably has pools for the token you're swapping from